# Cannot download drivers in DBeaver on Mac - reason: central.maven.org

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, tcp, dbeaver

I'm trying to download/update drivers as I'm getting a TCP/IP error when trying to connect to SQL server:

*The TCP/IP connection to the host XXX, port 1433 has failed. Error: "XXX. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".*

but when I try to download I'm getting a 'Driver download failed', *Reason: central.maven.org*.

Can't find much on this issue. Please see photos.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it still a problem for you? Microsoft just suffered a [20+ hour outage](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/246136621) that affected most of their packages.microsoft.com software deliveries.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Maven Central is not owned nor hosted by Microsoft